# The doInBackground() method in the AsyncTask gets executed only sometimes

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using the `AsyncTask` to render a graph from a list. Sometimes it works alright and the graph is rendered. However in some cases the graph is not being rendered, and the reason for this is that the `doInBackground()` method is not being triggered. Here's the code of the `AsyncTask`.

```
private class HistoryPlotAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    boolean isAnalysisMode = false;
    List<Byte> listECG;
    List<Byte> listHS;

    HistoryPlotAsync(List<Byte> listECG, List<Byte> listHS, List<Byte> listMur, boolean isAnalysisMode) {
        this.listECG = listECG;
        this.listHS = listHS;
        this.isAnalysisMode = isAnalysisMode;
        HistoryPlot.this.multiHsRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
        HistoryPlot.this.multiEcgRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (HistoryPlot.this.pcgPlayer != null) {
            HistoryPlot.this.pcgPlayer.start();
        } else {
            try {
                HistoryPlot.this.startSound();
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        int loopCounter = 0;
        if (this.listHS != null && this.listHS.size() > 0) {
            loopCounter = this.listHS.size();
        }
        double xValue = 0.0d;
        double xValueEcg = 0.0d;
        do {
            xValueEcg += 0.0015625d;
            if (this.listHS != null && i % 2 == 0) {
                xValue += 0.0032012d;
                hsSeries.add(xValue,listHS.get((i/2)));
            }
            try {
                if (this.listECG != null && i < this.listECG.size()) {
                    ecgSeries.add(xValueEcg, listECG.get(i));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    Log.d("HistoryPlot -> ", "doInBackground: Exception " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    Log.e("HistoryPlot -> ", "Error in Analysis mode point conversion");
                }
            }
            if (i > HistoryPlot.this.refRange && i % 94 == 0) {
                HistoryPlot.this.xMin = HistoryPlot.this.xMin + 0.15d;
                HistoryPlot.this.xMax = HistoryPlot.this.xMax + 0.15d;
                HistoryPlot.this.multiHsRenderer.setXAxisMin(HistoryPlot.this.xMin);
                HistoryPlot.this.multiHsRenderer.setXAxisMax(HistoryPlot.this.xMax);
                HistoryPlot.this.multiEcgRenderer.setXAxisMin(HistoryPlot.this.xMin);
                HistoryPlot.this.multiEcgRenderer.setXAxisMax(HistoryPlot.this.xMax);
            }
            if (i % 16 == 0) {
                publishProgress(new Void[0]);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            i++;
            if (i >= loopCounter) {
                break;
            }
        } while (!HistoryPlot.this.taskHistoryPlot.isCancelled());
        return null;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        HistoryPlot.this.mHsChart.repaint();
        HistoryPlot.this.mEcgChart.repaint();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        HistoryPlot.this.stopSound();
        HistoryPlot.this.enableReplay();
        HistoryPlot.this.multiHsRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
        HistoryPlot.this.multiEcgRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    }
}
```

The AsyncTask is executed via the following code in the onCreate() method of the Activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
...
this.taskHistoryPlot = new HistoryPlotAsync((List) mapData.get("fileEcg"), (List) mapData.get("fileHs"), (List) mapData.get("fileMur"), isAnalysisMode);
this.taskHistoryPlot.execute();
}
```

Instead of using the `execute()` method, I have also tried using the `executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` method with the same results.

Comment: apply breakpoint at doInbackground... To check if it comes there everytime, if it comes then there is error with your conditions in the block also check where you call it if there are any conditions to run that.

Comment: I had placed a log at the very beginning of the method before the said check, to verify the same. The doInBackground() is not called.
Debugging also returns the same results. doInBackground is called sometimes, whereas sometimes it isn't.

Comment: Is there any exception on log ?

Comment: The problem is with the code before the call probably, can you provide the code in "...." on the onCreate fuction?

Comment: The log isn't printed when the doInBackground doesn't run. So no exception.

Comment: Ohh buddy are you calling it onCreate of activity because onCreate runs one time only there may be an issue of activity lifecycle

Comment: @TomásRodrigues I'm unable to provide that code. But all the code leading upto the asynctask.execute() executes without any problem.

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan I'll check out this lead and get back to you.

Comment: Ok sure mate hope u will get it working soon. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I tried this but it did not work out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the issue resolved using the following code. The problem was that I had simply tried using the execute() method and the executeOnExecutor() method as is. You need to define an Executor and a Blocking Queue variables and define pool sizes for this to work.

```
static int mCorePoolSize = 60;
static int mMaximumPoolSize = 80;
static int mKeepAliveTime = 10;

static BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(mMaximumPoolSize);
static Executor mCustomThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(mCorePoolSize, mMaximumPoolSize, mKeepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);

this.taskHistoryPlot = new HistoryPlotAsync((List) mapData.get("fileEcg"), (List) mapData.get("fileHs"), (List) mapData.get("fileMur"), isAnalysisMode);
this.taskHistoryPlot.executeOnExecutor(mCustomThreadPoolExecutor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Asynctask methods will surely run, if you have have call to this class.
Please debug that, the conditions inside doInBackground(), for example 
"if (HistoryPlot.this.pcgPlayer != null) "
because it may be possible that condition is not working well, or throws xception and led the function not being called.

Comment: I had placed a log at the very beginning of the method before the said check, to verify the same. The doInBackground() is not called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that code to execute multiple times, do not use the onCreate function. Create one that you can call everytime you want, onCreate() only runs once in the Activity lifecycle. That can be the cause.

You can call it from the onCreate as well, if you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace these two lines:

```
this.taskHistoryPlot = new HistoryPlotAsync((List) mapData.get("fileEcg"), (List) mapData.get("fileHs"), (List) mapData.get("fileMur"), isAnalysisMode);
this.taskHistoryPlot.execute();
```

with:

```
new HistoryPlotAsync((List) mapData.get("fileEcg"), (List) mapData.get("fileHs"), (List) mapData.get("fileMur"), isAnalysisMode).execute();
```

You dont need to pass context of activity here "this." will give the context of activity which you dont need it here so apply above mentioned changes.

OnCreate will run it one time only create another method in which you need to run your async task and call that new method wherever you want.You can also call that method in onCreate too.

Comment: Bro do this in that way that this thing is giving context of the activity in which you are calling it in you don't need that here just execute you new asynctask directly. Remove two lines and any variables associated with that and directly execute new task single liner as I described above.

Comment: Let me know if this will solve your issue otherwise if you have any problems also tell me about them. Dont forget to mark my post as answer if it works for you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Moreover this will run only in oncreate if you are not calling it again if you need to call it again then again execute new one as described above. Because it will go to background thread and when it completes it will do the job onPostExecute and will kill itself if you need it again create a new one wherever you need.